# Método sem código nenhum

Tags: c#

Seguindo um livro, criei um projeto `windows forms application`. Coloquei no `form` um `textBox` e um `button`. No `onclick` do `button` pego o valor do `textBox` e o atribuo ao text do `form`.

O livro pede para você olhar o método `InitializeComponents()` do `form`. Então me deparei com o método `SuspendLayout()`. Fui até o método para ver o que ele fazia e não havia código nenhum nele. Mas pesquisando, pelo que eu entendi, quando é adicionado vários controles (entendo como `buttons`, `textBox`, etc.) o `SuspendLayout()` se encarrega de montar o layout após processar todos eles, fazendo com que o aplicativo tenha um melhor desempenho. O que acho estranho é o método não ter código, onde é que está esse código afinal? Não é a primeira vez que entro num método e não tem nada lá dentro.

```
partial class frmMain
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 95);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 67);
            this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
            this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // frmMain
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 253);
            this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "frmMain";
            this.Text = "frmMain";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    }
```

Comment: Dê mais contexto, mostre o código. É uma classe `partial`?

Comment: Não sei o que é partial, vou pesquisar. Mas adicionei o código no post.

Comment: Onde está o método vazio?

Comment: Onde você olhou o código desse método? Ele é parte do .Net Framework, mais especificamente da classe Control do WindowsForms, o código fonte você pode ver aqui: [https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,12393](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,12393)

Comment: Acho que a dúvida dele é quando navegamos por algum método/objeto do `framework`(F12 no VS) e é mostrado o que aquele `framework` implementa

Comment: Se for com o F12 por padrão o VS.Net mostra apenas os metadados, então aparece apenas os nomes dos métodos e não o código fonte

Comment: O que eu não entendo é um método fazer algo, no caso SuspendLayout(), e não ter código nenhum lá dentro.

Comment: @HeyJoe olhe o link que passei no meu primeiro comentário

Comment: @Maniero o método SuspendLayout() está dentro do método InitializeComponents(), coloquei o código no post. E esse método SuspendLayout() está na classe public class Control.

Comment: Também não sei o que são metadados. Eu vi o link, parece que os códigos estão lá naquele site, então o VS busca os códigos lá? Agora faz sentido.

Comment: Não, dentro do `InitializeComponents()` está apenas chamando o `SuspendLayout()`, o método em si não está lá.

Comment: @Maniero sim, era isso o que eu queria dizer, mas não coloquei com as palavras certas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como leandro mencionou nos comentários, acredito que esteja tentando ver o código do método apertando F12 e aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como mostra na imagem, `from metadata` isso significa que o método está vindo da biblioteca já compilada (no caso `System.Windows.Forms.dll`) e você tem acesso as assinaturas dos métodos mas não ao código deles.

Para saber o que o método faz, você tem que acessar a documentação da Microsoft (ou seja, de quem fez a biblioteca): https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx

E não, o visual studio não busca os códigos de nenhum site. Você pode sim adicionar pacotes pelo nuget, etc, mas aí é um comando que você tem que executar.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você diz que o método não tem código, eu imagino que você deva ter navegado até a definição do método usando o Visual Studio (F12 na configuração de atalhos padrão) e lá não ter encontrado nenhuma lógica.

É possível configurar o Visual Studio para exibir (e até mesmo debugar o fonte do Framework). Outra maneira de inspecionar o código fonte da implementação do .NET Framework é através do site "Reference Source", da própria Microsoft, que permite navegar e fazer pesquisas no fonte..

No caso do SuspendLayout(), você pode ver mais detalhes da implementação do método na classe Control neste link https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,ef45260c5d9215da

[image: Imagem mostrando a implementação do Método SuspendLayout]

Suas conclusões sobre o SuspendLayout() estão corretas. Ao invocar o SuspendLayout(), o processamento da lógica de layout do controle é interrompida, ou seja, você pode fazer múltiplas alterações de layout (tamanho, posicionamento, cor, docking, anchoring, etc) sem que o controle seja renderizado sempre que alguma propriedade é alterada. Ao invocar o ResumeLayout() as alterações são efetivadas todas de uma vez.

Espero ter ajudado a esclarecer.

Abs